# My variables don't work and am getting a weird error code using discord

Tags: python, discord.py

```
if message.content.startswith('!annoy'):
mseg = ('who do you want to Annoy?')
await client.send_message(message.channel, mseg)
responses = client.wait_for_message(author=message.author)
myvart = responses.content
if message.content.startswith(myvart):
  msg = ('Have fun, pleb...')
  await client.send_message(message.channel,msg)
  no = 0
  while no != 50:
    time.sleep(1)
    await 
   client.send_message(client.get_member_named('myvart'), 
   random.choice(insults))
    no = no + 1
```

**The Error Code i'm Getting is here:**

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 41, in on_message
    myvart = message.responses.content
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'responses'
```

Edit;;Message output on discord is:

!annoy

who do you want to Annoy?

```
<generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a94d19e8>
<generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a94d1990>
<generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a94d1678>
<generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a9510c50>
<generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a94d16d0>
<generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a9510830>
```

Comment: Have you tried simplifying to `myvart = client.wait_for_message(author=message.author).content`?

Comment: no ill see if that works

Comment: nah diddn't work

Answer (score 1):

[`Client.wait_for_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message) is a coroutine, and must be `await`ed:

```
responses = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author)
```

Similarly, one of your `send_messages` is missing an `await`, and you should be using `asyncio.sleep` over `time.sleep` so as not to block the event loop.

Comment: so now i don't have any errors but i still get: <generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a94d1678>
<generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a9510c50>
<generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a94d16d0>
<generator object Client.get_all_members at 0x7f15a9510830>

Comment: Do you have other code that could be sending messages that isn't here? I don't see a call to `get_all_members` in this code

Comment: i did but i took it out so i dont know what could be causing it, it also spams that endlessly so i dont really know

Answer (score 0):

The error says the line of code that is giving you trouble is:

```
myvart = message.responses.content
```

This message goes on to explain that:

> 'Message' object has no attribute 'responses'

You can find **ALL** the available attributes for a `Message` at: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message

And there you will see that `Message.content` is a valid thing to call. Therefore, I recommend you replace

```
myvart = message.responses.content
```

With:

```
myvart = message.content
```

Comment: I fixed it i had a random get all members line in there its fixd now